# Как сделать таблицу БД неопределённой длины SQL

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Часто встречаюсь с проблемой неопределённости с количеством столбцов в таблице. Пример:

```
Таблица_1: №т.|товар|цена
Таблица_2: №с.|№т.|№т.|№т.|№т.
Таблица_3: №з.|заказ|№с.
```

Как видно на примере в "Таблица_2" может быть так что количество товара станет больше 4. Мой вариант решения:

```
Таблица_1: №т.|товар|цена
Таблица_2: №с.|№т.|№т.|№т.|№т.|№с.{+1} //список товаров для покупки
Таблица_3: №з.|заказ|№с.
```

т.е. при достижении лимита создаётся новая запись в "Таблица_2" а в предыдущей в последнем столбце номер на следующую. Не уж то нет более красивого варианта?

Comment: Либо Вы не понимаете о чем говорите либо я не понимаю о чем говорите Вы. 

Пока что я себя чувствую глупым, потому что не понял. Не могли бы Вы переформулировать вопрос?

Comment: возможно я пропустил какой-то этап описания. Мне необходимо создать архитектуру БД, где в одной из таблиц периодически может не хватать столбцов для внесения данных, таких как например перечисление товаров в корзине. Товаров в корзине может быть совсем мало, либо очень много. Как поступить в данном случае, чтобы это было максимально экономично в плане ресурсов (времени разработки, места на диске, процессорного времени обработки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

№с - номер связи?
Обычно делают так:

```
T1: №т.|... // Товары
T2: №з.|... // Заказы
T3: №з.|№т. // Связи
```

Ну и что-то вроде

```
SELECT * FROM [T3] WHERE [№з.] = 123
```

Comment: в строке >>T3: №з.|№т. // Связи<< вы случайно не допустили описки? >>Nc.<<

под №с. я имел в виду порядковый номер списка товаров. 

Честно говоря мне совсем не понятно что вы написали. Можете расписать?

Comment: Думаю, запрос в гугле "связь многие ко многим" спасёт вас.

Answer (score 4):

Я тоже мало что понял. Однако считаю, что при правильном проектировании добавляться должны строки, а не столбцы. И тогда у вас не будет подобных проблем. Но без знания предметной области мне трудно посоветовать конкретную структуру.